# Can I start with my identity card unrezzed?

Tags: android-netrunner

The rules state

> There are six types of Corporation cards: identities, operations, agendas, ice, upgrades, and assets... Corporation cards are installed facedown, and are inactive unless rezzed.

Does that mean if I'm playing as the corp I can start with my identity card unrezzed (and therefore inactive and providing no bonus), or must I reveal my identity to the runner immediately? Or is it special and not technically "installed"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the very start of the Setup section the rules read:

> 1. Choose Sides: The players decide who will play as the  Runner and who will play as the Corporation. Then, each  player places his
>      identity card faceup in his play area and  takes a corresponding deck.

Initial identities go face up.  It's only subsequently that Corporation cards should be installed facedown.

"Rezzing" is furthermore defined as "the act of flipping a facedown card faceup"; so if the initial identities are faceup, there can be no question of them starting the game "unrezzed" (if that wasn't already obvious).